# Destroying dynamically created component throws change detection error

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-components, angular2-changedetection

I'm attempting to destroy a dynamically created component which is inserted into a modal window. The component code is

```
import {Component, Input, Output, OnInit, EventEmitter, OnDestroy} from '@angular/core';
import {NgSwitch, NgSwitchCase, NgSwitchDefault} from '@angular/common';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl, Validators, REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/forms';

import {ControlType, DateTimeValidationType} from '../Types/enums';
import {IFormBuilderField} from '../Types/interfaces';
import {ValidationFormBuilderService} from '../Services/validation-form-builder.service';
import {OptionsFormBuilderService} from '../Services/options-form-builder.service';
import {NumberControlComponent} from '../../NumberControl/Components/number-control.component';

import {BaseComponent} from '../../../App/Shared/Components/base.component';
import {isUnique} from '../../../App/Shared/Helpers/fieldValidators';
import {TagCreatorComponent} from '../../../App/Shared/Components/tag-creator.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'field-editor',
    templateUrl: 'templates/resources/formBuilder/field-editor.component.html',
    directives: [
        REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES,
        NgSwitch,
        NgSwitchCase,
        NgSwitchDefault,
        TagCreatorComponent,
        NumberControlComponent],
    providers: [ValidationFormBuilderService, OptionsFormBuilderService]
})

export class FieldEditorComponent extends BaseComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    constructor(
        private _formBuilder: FormBuilder,
        private _validationFormBuilder: ValidationFormBuilderService,
        private _optionsFormBuilder: OptionsFormBuilderService) {
        super();
    }
    DateTimeValidationType = DateTimeValidationType;
    ControlType = ControlType;
    @Input() field: IFormBuilderField;
    @Output() update: EventEmitter<IFormBuilderField> = new EventEmitter<IFormBuilderField>();
    @Input() labels: string[];
    form: FormGroup;
    label: FormControl;
    control: FormControl;

    validationForm: FormGroup;
    optionsForm: FormGroup;

    validationFormSubscription: any;
    optionsFormSubscription: any;
    controlSubscription: any;
    formSubscription: any;

    controlOptions = Object.keys(ControlType)
        .filter(x => typeof ControlType[x] === "number")
        .map(x => ({
            value: ControlType[x],
            label: x
        }));

    dateTimeValidationOptions = Object.keys(DateTimeValidationType)
        .filter(x => typeof DateTimeValidationType[x] === "number")
        .map(x => ({
            value: DateTimeValidationType[x],
            label: x
        }));

    ngOnInit() {
        this.form = this._formBuilder.group({
            label: [this.field.label, Validators.compose(
                [Validators.required, isUnique(this.labels)])],
            control: [this.field.control]
        });
        this.buildValidationForm();
        this.buildOptionsForm();
        this.label = this.form.controls['label'] as FormControl;
        this.control = this.form.controls['control'] as FormControl;

        this.controlSubscription = this.control.valueChanges.subscribe((control: ControlType) => {
            this.field.validation = {};
            this.buildValidationForm(+control);
            this.field.config = <any>{};
            this.buildOptionsForm(+control);
        });

        this.formSubscription = this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(form => {
            // Needs to be a number, but selects give a string value
            form.control = +form.control;
            Object.assign(this.field, form);
            this.update.emit(this.field);
        });
    }
    buildValidationForm(type: ControlType = this.field.control) {
        this.validationForm = this._validationFormBuilder.createForm(
            +type,
            this.field.validation);

        this.validationFormSubscription && this.validationFormSubscription.unsubscribe();

        this.validationFormSubscription = this.validationForm.valueChanges.subscribe(validationOptions => {
            this.field.validation = validationOptions;
            this.update.emit(this.field);
        });
    }
    buildOptionsForm(type: ControlType = this.field.control) {
        this.optionsForm = this._optionsFormBuilder.createForm(
            +type,
            this.field.config);

        this.optionsFormSubscription && this.optionsFormSubscription.unsubscribe();

        this.optionsFormSubscription = this.optionsForm.valueChanges.subscribe(options => {
            this.field.config = options;
            this.update.emit(this.field);
        });
    }
    getDateTimeValidationControl(firstLevel: string, name: string) {
        return (<FormGroup>this.validationForm.controls[firstLevel + "DateTime"]).controls[name];
    }
    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.controlSubscription.unsubscribe();
        this.optionsFormSubscription.unsubscribe();
        this.validationFormSubscription.unsubscribe();
        this.formSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

with the modal window being displayed via this service

```
import {
    Injectable,
    ComponentRef,
    Inject,
    ComponentResolver,
    Injector,
    ViewChild,
    ViewContainerRef} from '@angular/core';

import {IModalInformation, IButton} from '../Types/interfaces';

@Injectable()
export class ModalService {
    constructor(
        @Inject(ComponentResolver) private _componentResolver: ComponentResolver) { }
    visible: boolean = false;
    title: string = null;
    body: any = null;
    isString: boolean;
    isArray: boolean;
    isComponent: boolean;
    componentRef: ComponentRef<any>;
    buttons: IButton[] = [];
    onClose: () => void = () => undefined;
    modalBody: ViewContainerRef;    //Assigned in the modal.component code correctly
    private renderComponent(component: any): Promise<ComponentRef<any>> {
        return this._componentResolver.resolveComponent(component)
            .then(componentFactory => {
                const ref = this.modalBody.createComponent(componentFactory);
                this.componentRef = ref;
                return Promise.resolve(ref);
            });
    }
    public show(modalInformation: IModalInformation) {
        this.isString = typeof this.body === "string";
        this.isArray = Array.isArray(this.body);
        this.isComponent = !this.isString && !this.isArray;

        this.visible = true;
        this.title = modalInformation.title;
        this.body = modalInformation.body;

        if (this.isComponent) {
            setTimeout(() => this.renderComponent(this.body.component).then(this.body.then), 0);
        }

        this.buttons = modalInformation.buttons;
        this.onClose = modalInformation.onClose;
    }
    public close() {
        if (!this.onClose()) {
            return;
        }
        if (this.isComponent) {
            this.componentRef.destroy();
            this.componentRef = null;
        }
        this.isComponent = false;
        this.visible = false;
        this.isArray = false;
        this.isString = false;
        this.title = null;
        this.body = null;
        this.onClose = () => undefined;
        this.buttons = [];
    }
}
```

The service is called by a parent component, which specifies the type of component to use and a callback to attach input and output properties to the component reference (the body proeprty).

The issue I am having is that when I attempt to destroy the dynamically created component (FieldEditorComponent) I get an error of

```
Error: Attempt to use a destroyed view: detectChanges
at ViewDestroyedException.BaseException [as constructor] (http://localhost:5000/js/app-es6.js:6500:23)
at new ViewDestroyedException (http://localhost:5000/js/app-es6.js:35885:16)
at DebugAppView.AppView.throwDestroyedError (http://localhost:5000/js/app-es6.js:36433:72)
at DebugAppView.AppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:5000/js/app-es6.js:36380:18)
at DebugAppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:5000/js/app-es6.js:36487:44)
at ViewRef_.detectChanges (http://localhost:5000/js/app-es6.js:36839:65)
at http://localhost:5000/js/app-es6.js:30325:84
at Array.forEach (native)
at ApplicationRef_.tick (http://localhost:5000/js/app-es6.js:30325:38)
at http://localhost:5000/js/app-es6.js:30229:125
```

As you can see I've tried to clear up the subscriptions in the FieldEditor, as well as first detaching the ChangeDetectorRef available on the ComponentRef being destroyed. Changing the ChangeDetectionStrategy to OnPush for the FieldEditor also hasn't helped. I've also tried all manner of setTimeouts around destroying the component, setting the reference to null, and removing the visibility of the modal.

The modal component itself is simply there to hold the html and get the modalBody ViewContainerRef, and the visible property on modalService works via 'display: none;' instead of via *ngIf.

Comment: remove `this.componentRef = null;` i think it will solve your problem

Comment: It doesn't, unfortunately.

Comment: i have made modal service that works quite well. If you want i can sent you the code so you can adapt it to your needs

Comment: have you solved this problem? I ran into this destroyed view problem this very minute, also trying to build a dialog service...